# Phonebook Search Method java.lang.NumberFormatException in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this android phonebook app, then I need to implement the add, edit, delete and search. But I'm having error with getting the input text for row in my Search Method.

I got this error in my logcat:

```
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactslocator/com.example.contactslocator.Search}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:347)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:320)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at com.example.contactslocator.Search.onCreate(Search.java:29)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-15 23:28:12.450: E/AndroidRuntime(407):  ... 11 more
```

line 29 is:

```
long l = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

My code snippet is:

```
String s = sqlRow.getText().toString();
long l = Integer.parseLong(s);

Save ss = new Save (this);
ss.open();
String returnedName = ss.getName(l);
String returnedAddress = ss.getAddress(l);
String returnedNumber = ss.getNumber(l);
String returnedZipcode = ss.getZipcode(l);
String returnedCategory = ss.getCategory(l);
ss.close();

sqlName.setText(returnedName);
sqlAddress.setText(returnedAddress);
sqlMobilenum.setText(returnedNumber);
sqlZipcode.setText(returnedZipcode);
sqlCategory.setText(returnedCategory);
```

I tried changing long to int, but I still got errors, `can't parse ''`

Why I'm getting this error in line 29?

Comment: `sqlRow.getText().toString()` appears to return an empty `String`.

Comment: General comment. Are you sure you want to do "long l = Integer.parseInt(s);"

Comment: How can I fix this? I want the user to enter the a number in the row. I'm wondering that, that could be the error but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's parseLong, forgot to edit it after I tried parseInt.

Comment: What kind object is `sqlRow`?